# How do I make the Input Exception for this method?

Tags: java

In method `public void setYear (int yearPassed)` (must be 1886 to 2014 inclusive) - what is the test for this part? I am really stuck here. I have just a while loop so how do you make it so you must enter 1886 to 2014. The scanner has to stay in this method and I'd like do it as simple as possible:

```
public void setYear(int yearPassed)
{ 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while(yearPassed <=0) //must be 1886 to 2014 (inclusive) How do I make it inclusive? 
    { 
        System.out.println("Number of years must be >= 0"); 
        System.out.println("Enter the number of years, must be >= 0"); 
        yearPassed = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    }

    year = yearPassed; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get into the `while` loop in the case of your year is not in the interval.
So you need to use this condition

```
 while (yearPassed > 2014 ||  yearPassed < 1886)///which mean you will inside the loop until you enter a yea in the interval
```

---

**Hint**: this loop includes `1886` and `2014`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use an if condition?

```
if(yearPassed < 1886 || yearPassed >=2014)
```